# How to run Red5 applications on a remote server?

Tags: java, red5

I've got a really nasty problem...

I wrote a [Red5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red5) app and so on and it is running perfectly on my local computer.
Now the problem occurs =>

How can I make this program work on a remote server?

```
Local : Mac OS X 10.5 - Red5 0.63 
Server: CentOS 5 - Red5 0.90
```

Maybe it's because of the version difference. But I can't test Red5 0.90 locally because it won't start up and I can't install the 0.63 version on the server because of missing dependencies (and broken links to them...)

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

- Without error messages, code, a description of your application, etc. we can't really help.
- Red5 has been in *very* active development over the years, and each tiny version change is significant.  I would suggest figuring out how to get Red5 0.9 running on your local machine would be your first priority.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it...

The XML files have totally changed in the last versions :D and I got a little bug in my program :P

Answer (score 0):

The primary change was in the web.xml, comparing your applications web.xml to one of the 0.9 demos will show you the differences.